# Python3 with Windows shared folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to fetch files from windows shared folder , but it's showing error

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:`

as I have tried following options:

- `print (os.listdir('\\piyushtech\techtech$\Piyush\Optimized Version'))`
- `print (os.listdir('\\\\piyushtech\techtech$\Piyush\Optimized Version'))`
- `print (os.listdir('\\\\piyushtech/techtech$/Piyush/Optimized Version'))`
- `print (os.listdir('/piyushtech/techtech$/Piyush/Optimized Version'))`

Nothing works.

Comment: Your original problem is that if you are going to use backslashes in the string, you must double *all* of them, not just the ones at the beginning. Or else use a raw string: `print (os.listdir(r'\\piyushtech\techtech$\Piyush\Optimized Version'))`

Comment: Ohh Thanks bro!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for an reference , following works for me

```
os.listdir('//piyushtech/techtech$/Piyush/Optimized Version')
```

Best way if you are using python3 is:-

```
from pathlib import Path
Path("\\piyushtech\techtech$\Piyush\Optimized Version")
```

See [this](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f)

Comment: next time take some minutes to review your question. any way good you figured it out